# What are the genus 4 curves with Jacobians that are 4-th powers?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, moduli-spaces, abelian-varieties

Consider the moduli space of all genus $4$ curves $\overline{\mathscr M_4}$ of dimension $3\times 4 - 3 = 9$. Under the Torelli map, there is a map to $\overline{\mathscr A_4}$ (which has dimension $10$) that is injective on $\mathbb C$ valued points.

On the other hand, consider the diagonal map $\Delta: \overline{\mathscr M}_{1,1}^4 \to \mathscr A_4$ whose image is one dimensional. Since the dimensions match up, the intersection of $\Delta$ with $\overline{\mathscr M_4}$ is a dimension zero scheme and corresponds to finitely many genus $4$ curves whose Jacobian is completely split into isomorphic elliptic curves (geometrically, over $\mathbb C$) - unless the diagonal is contained in the image of the Torelli locus!?

What is the intersection number here/ what is known about these finitely many genus $4$ curves.

I found [this](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250281052) paper that gives $3$ examples of such genus $4$ curves but what else is known?

Comment: Sorry, why is the image of $M_{1,1}^4$ one dimensional? It seems like it should be four dimensional. Or did you mean to ask only about genus four curves whose Jacobian is a fourth power?

Comment: Right, that is the diagonal map. Sorry! I should clarify.

Comment: Maybe you mean that the Jacobian is isogenous (not isomorphic) to the fourth power of an elliptic curve. Maybe this weaker condition alters finiteness.

Comment: $\mathscr{A}_4$ is the moduli space of *principally polarized* abelian varieties of dimension $4$. Jacobians in $\mathscr{A}_4$ are irreducible, and therefore *never* isomorphic to a product (as p.p.a.v.'s).